# Firebug: wrong language

Tags: language, firebug

Since updating to Firebug 1.9, the interface has suddenly changed to Dutch. I'm mystified as to how that's happened, because my machine is entirely configured in English.

How can I switch it back to my default locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog post](http://webstylingtricks.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-change-firebug-language.html#firebug-language-method2) provided a simple solution:

1. In the address bar type `about:config`.
2. Find the parameter named `extensions.firebug.useDefaultLocale`.
3. Double-click on it and change its value from `false` to `true`.